# New file created path

Tags: java, android

I was referring to this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal for write file in internal memory. Where do I check the file? For an example the guide code:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Where do I go and check the file hello_file, since the guide didn't give the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created the file in the  `EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, then you can check the same in the sdcard by browsing through the sdcard. Or check in the `/mnt/sdcard/...` in the File explorer tab.

If you have created the file in the `INTERNAL_STORAGE` then you can check in the `/data/data...` path. But you wont be able to browse `/data/data` path if your phone is not rooted.

Answer (score 1):

Check it in the /data/data/yourpackagename/file/hello_file path.

Answer (score 1):

In your eclipse if you are using emulator. go to the following path to find the file you have created in application field.
     /data/data/yourpackagename/file/hello_file path.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `adb` to access your phone from shell and go to your apps private storage directory

```
adb shell
```

execute the following commands

```
> cd data/data/org.yourpackage.yourapp/files
> ls
```

You may also pull your file to your computer with

```
adb pull /pathtofile/file
```