# Where are files stored on an Android emulator?

Tags: android, file, file-io, android-emulator

I am working on a small program on Android to write some hard-coded text to a file with a hard-coded name. While the operation is successful (there are no errors), I am not able to find the file on the emulator. My questions:

1. Where are the files written?
2. What is the file path I need for files to be stored on the home screen or the applications page (in general, a place where the UI can get to)?

The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button writeFile;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    writeFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.writeFile);
    writeFile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //Step 1. Get file name.
                String file = "hello_files.txt";
                String str = "hello world";

                Log.v(this.toString(), "Going to write to a file.");
                FileOutputStream fos;
                try {
                    fos = openFileOutput(file, MODE_WORLD_READABLE | MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                    fos.write(str.getBytes());
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "Local path = ");
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "File not found!!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "IO Exception.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Files are stored in "/mnt/sdcard/" (External storage) or "/data/data/Your Package Name/" (Internal storage) (as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373375/new-file-created-path)). You can access this folder from this package only (unless the phone is rooted).

The second part of your question is not very clear. From what I can understand, Android is not like Windows (no desktop folder). To create a shortcut on the desktop, you need to implement an App widget.