# i'm tring to create a file text

Tags: android, file

hi guys i'm a biginner in java and android world. 
it's the first time i ask help on stackoverflow.com

i'm tryng to create a file text in my first app android.

this is a sample code

```
String string = nome;
try {
    File file = new File("prova.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos =null;
    if (file.exists() ) {
       fos = new FileOutputStream("prova.txt", true);
        PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(fos);
        print.append(nome);
        print.close();


    } else if (file.createNewFile()) {

        PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(file);
        print.println(nome);
        print.close();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the app doesn't create the file. 
can you give me an hand ?
can you explain me why ?

many thanks

Comment: take a look at this answer it should work and its well commented: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7718374/1173391

Comment: Also make sure to add the permission that allows you to access external storage: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code from here: http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html

You can always make changes to get your result

```
//Writing a file...  



try { 
       // catches IOException below
       final String TESTSTRING = new String("Hello Android");

       /* We have to use the openFileOutput()-method
       * the ActivityContext provides, to
       * protect your file from others and
       * This is done for security-reasons.
       * We chose MODE_WORLD_READABLE, because
       *  we have nothing to hide in our file */             
       FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("samplefile.txt",
                                                            MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
       OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 

       // Write the string to the file
       osw.write(TESTSTRING);

       /* ensure that everything is
        * really written out and close */
       osw.flush();
       osw.close();

//Reading the file back...

       /* We have to use the openFileInput()-method
        * the ActivityContext provides.
        * Again for security reasons with
        * openFileInput(...) */

        FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("samplefile.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);

        /* Prepare a char-Array that will
         * hold the chars we read back in. */
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[TESTSTRING.length()];

        // Fill the Buffer with data from the file
        isr.read(inputBuffer);

        // Transform the chars to a String
        String readString = new String(inputBuffer);

        // Check if we read back the same chars that we had written out
        boolean isTheSame = TESTSTRING.equals(readString);

        Log.i("File Reading stuff", "success = " + isTheSame);

    } catch (IOException ioe) 
      {ioe.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) @Vincenzo Carriero :)

I think you've missed the **permission**, otherwise your code seems fine.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Helping links :

- [Saving Files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)
- [How to create a file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239026/how-to-create-a-file-in-android?lq=1)

---

**Edit :** Have you debugged your application? If you get exception like ***"java.io.IOException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)"***, then it means there is a problem in your file path. You need to write the file path like :

```
String filePath =this.getFilesDir().getPath().toString()+"/fileName.txt";
File f = new File(filePath);
```

**Note :** I've used `**this**.getFilesDir()` because I was coding inside an *Activity*. 
If you store a File using above mentioned *filePath* your file will be stored at : "*/data/data/[package name]/[file name].txt*".

Please take a look at following helping links :

- [Saving Files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)
- [Where are files stored on an Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998098/where-are-files-stored-on-an-android-emulator/12998540#12998540)

Comment: @Vincenzo Carriero do you have an actual device or you're using emulator?

Comment: i'm using an emulator . could be the problem?

Comment: @Vincenzo Carriero Have you debugged, any exceptions?